# Retrieving table names from Access, can't open microsoft jet engine workgroup information file

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to read the table names from an access database file using code I found from another stack overflow question about doing just that. The code is below:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name 
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE (((Left([Name], 1)) <> "~") '
  AND ((Left([Name], 4)) <> "MSys") 
  AND ((MSysObjects.Type) In (1, 4, 6))) 
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name
```

However when I run this I get the error `Record(s) cannot be read; no read permissions on 'MSysObjects'`and after some research I found a way to grant the read access needed.

I added `'GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin'` and I now get the error: `Cannot open the microsoft jet engine workgroup information file.` and every article I've seen about this error refers to either an issue with Kaspersky (which this computer isn't running) or an issue with the System.mdw file, which doesn't seem to be the problem because running any other command works just fine.

How can I get around this issue so I can read in the table names?

Comment: if you show the hidden objects in the mdb file can you access them then? http://www.techonthenet.com/access/database/view_hiddentbls2007.php shows how to display them in the .mdb.

Comment: Yes I can open it from within access

Comment: This is through a SQL server query or through an access query?

Comment: Do you even have a workgroup file connected to the database? What version of Access are you using?

Comment: This is being done through a TADOQuery in Delphi. It's access 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done the SP6 update to your VB6 install?  It is necessary for VB6 to open MS Access 2000 or later MDB's

Comment: I'm able to connect and pull data from one of the tables in the database already, the only time I get this error is when I try to give myself select access and try to pull data from the MSysObjects table.